# Cannot build Open3D from source

Tags: c++, cmake, open3d

I'm trying to build Open3D from source in c++. I have followed the method explained [here](https://github.com/isl-org/open3d-cmake-find-package), but when it enable the flag -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON I get this message:

```
CMake Error at 3rdparty/webrtc/webrtc_download.cmake:15 (message):
Pre-built WebRTC binaries are not available for BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON or
STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME=OFF.  Please use (a) BUILD_WEBRTC=OFF or (b)
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF and STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME=ON or (c)
BUILD_WEBRTC_FROM_SOURCE=ON
```

When I then disable BUILD_WEBRTC I'm able to generate the project. However, when I then try to build the INSTALL in visual studio I can the following error:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Open3DConfig.obj
```

Hopefully someone knows how to fix this problem :)

Comment: Maybe you need to use option (b). The error means incompatibility in required runtime library. It expects static runtime, but you are building for dynamic runtime.

Comment: @kiner_shah thank you for the reply. I need to have shared_libs= ON so b) is not an option  for me

Comment: @kiner_shah I have now tried option c) where I have set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON, BUILD_WEBRTC=OFF and BUILD_WEBRTC_FROM_SOURCE=ON.    This produces the same error as previously. Do you have any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `CMakeLists.txt` for Open3D, when you set the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` the following is also set:

```
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  option(STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME "Use static (MT/MTd) Windows runtime"      OFF)
else()
  option(STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME "Use static (MT/MTd) Windows runtime"      ON )
endif()
```

Are you sure that you have the `STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME=OFF` while still using `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`?